# Using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to load beans

Tags: spring

This is my interface

```
public interface PersonneService {
    public void add(Personne personne);
    public void delete (int PersonneID);
    public Personne getPersonne(int PersonneID); 
    public List getAllPersonne();
}
```

this is my class main

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.test.model.Personne;

public class PersonneServiceTest {
 private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;
 private static PersonneService personneService;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
        personneService=(PersonneService) context.getBean("PersonneService");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        context.close();
    }
```

This is error

```
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFOS: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1b10f9a: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1b10f9a]; startup date [Mon Jun 23 11:03:13 WEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
juin 23, 2014 11:03:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFOS: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]
juin 23, 2014 11:03:14 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFOS: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1b10f9a]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@648a34
```

Here is some error while I am doing a sample project in Spring. My application-context.xml is in src but it doesn't work:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException
```

Comment: What is it that does not work?

Comment: the load folder Application-Context.xml  is my folder beans and this error appear always

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors...

Comment: There is no error in the excerpt you supplied

Comment: ' org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFOS: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1b10f9a: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1b10f9a]; startup date [Mon Jun 23 11:03:13 WEST 2014];

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I did not pay attention:)

Comment: Add "antlr" jar to your project's classpath. Are you using Maven?

Comment: this jar  it is already in lib folder but always the same problem , no i am not use maven